# How do I keep the value when I refresh the browser and move the page while using mobx?

Tags: reactjs

We are currently using next.js to ssr. Refreshing or going back on a specific page initializes all stores.

I've been thinking about mobx-persist to solve this problem, but mobx-persist seems to only work in a browser environment.

Here's the question.

1. Is there a way to keep the value of a particular element in the store whenever I refresh the browser without using mobx-persist?
2. Is there a way to get the retained elements of the store from the ssr environment?
   Cookies, sessions, mobx-persist were not available in the ssr environment.

Below is the current react setting.

app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import { UserStore } from '../stores/userStore'

//_app.js
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const userStore = UserStore(pageProps.initialState)

    return (
        <Provider
            UserStore={userStore}
        >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default App
```

userStore.js

```
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
useStaticRendering(isServer)

class Store {
    @observable initialData = null
    @observable userId = null
    @observable userPw = null

    // @action...

    hydrate = async (initialState) => { // SSR INIT
        // this.initialState = initialState
    }
    

    export function initUserStore(initialState = null) {
           this.hydrate(initialState)
        // return store
    })

    export function UserStore(initialState) {
        const store = useMemo(() => initUserStore(initialState), [initialState])
        return store
    }

}
```

index.js (ssr)

```
// index.js ssr
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const UserStore = initUserStore() // store init
    // How can I get the value of the element (userId, userPw) of the store when it is in a refresh or server-side environment?
    .
    .
    .
    return {
        // props :{
            // initialState:{

            // }
        }
    }
})
```

The key issue is to import elements stored in the in the getServerSideProps(ssr) environment without store initialization after refresh.

Comment: This is determined by actual meaning of persistence on server side. There are no localStorage, etc. but databases. It's very specific to what kind of data it is. You need to identify a user, e.g. with a cookie from client side. Then you can fetch data that is related to this session (basically ctx.req.headers.cookie). If a cookie contains all necessary data, use it as without fetching.

Comment: Thank you for the good information. Do you know how to maintain the elements of mobx stores?

Comment: By using mobx-persist or similar approach. Client-side JS needs to store data somewhere between page reloads, there's no magic that allows to avoid cookies, local storage or else.